# Bash & Printf: How can I both right pad and truncate?

Tags: bash, printf, padding, truncate

In Bash ...

I know how to right pad with printf

```
printf "%-10s" "potato"
```

I know how to truncate with printf

```
printf "%.10s" "potatos are my best friends"
```

How can I do both at the same time?

```
LIST="aaa bbbbb ccc ddddd"
for ITEM in $LIST; do
  printf "%-.4s blah" $ITEM
done
```

This prints

```
aaa blah
bbbbb blah
ccc blah
ddddd blah
```

I want it to print

```
aaa  blah
bbbb blah
ccc  blah
dddd blah
```

I'd rather not do something like this (unless there's no other option):

```
LIST="aaa bbbbb ccc ddddd"
for ITEM in $LIST; do
  printf "%-4s blah" $(printf "%.4s" "$ITEM")
done
```

though, obviously, that works (it feels ugly and hackish).

Comment: I don't think there's much wrong with your approach - if anything is _ugly and hackish_, it's using a string as a "list". It would be nicer to use an array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `printf "%-4.4s` for getting both formatting in output:

```
for ITEM in $LIST; do printf "%-4.4s blah\n" "$ITEM"; done
aaa  blah
bbbb blah
ccc  blah
dddd blah
```